# two javascript files conflicting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-deployment

i have used fancybox on my webpage. and also used another slider that use the following javascript file

```
<script src="NewsSlider/Allmaritim.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the problem is, fancybox is not working properly. when i remove the upper javascript file then fancybox work fine.

Is there any way to keep javascript files working separately.

Comment: Can you tell us the error you got ....go with console messages..

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ read about this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356879/conflict-between-fancybox-and-other-jquery

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Hamid. Please don't post the same question again, but rather edit your first question to improve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be that you have similar functions[at least function names] defined in both files. Is your fancy box attached to a click or onload event? Otherwise, reorder how you include your files: that is, include Allmaritim.all.min.js after your fancy box script. If this file is not required in before loading, you might as well include at the bottom of you page!

Comment: ohh thanx. it works with the reordering the js files.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably both using jquery

try calling `jQuery.noConflict(true);` between the two javascript calls to the two scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.noConflict(); or jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes javascript library variables, names conflicts with others. As with the `jQuery`
$ variable can sometimes conflicts other libraries. They offer a solution that `[noConflict]` [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). So you need to read the documentation of these javascript libraries for the solution of conflicting problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html><head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="log">
    <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
    </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script>
    var $log = $( "#log" );
    $log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
    jq162 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    $log.append( "<h3>After $.noConflict(true)</h3>" );
    $log.append( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
    $log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jq162): " + jq162.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
</script></body></html>
```

Look into this sample code. 
Please Refer this link for more information http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/.